# Prove that the order of the cyclic subgroup $\langle g^k\rangle $ is $n/{\operatorname{gcd}(n,k)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, cyclic-groups, gcd-and-lcm

Let $G$ be a cyclic group of finite order $n$. Then, the order of the cyclic subgroup $\langle g^k\rangle$ is $\frac {n}{\operatorname{gcd}(n,k)}$

**Proof:**

$G$ cyclic $\Rightarrow \exists g \in G: G = \langle g\rangle$
$\Rightarrow \operatorname{ord}(g) = \lvert G\rvert = n $

We know, because every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic, that $\lvert\langle g^k\rangle\rvert =  \operatorname{ord}(g^k)$. Therefore, we only need to find the order of $g^k$.

Let $l$ be the order of $g^k$. Then:

$(g^k)^l = e \iff g^{kl} = e \iff n|(kl)$

I'm now trying to show that $l = n/{\operatorname{gcd}(n,k)}$, but this seems difficult for me. I tried to assume that there was an element $l' < n/{\operatorname{gcd}(n,k)}$ that satisfied the conditions, in the hope of reaching a contradiction, but this did not work out. Can anyone help?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2216035/589.

Comment: Instead of assuming that $G$ is cyclic of order $n$, you should probably assume that $G=\langle g\rangle$ and $g$ has order $n$. Otherwise, the conclusion doesn't make much sense ($g$ is undefined, it could very well be the identity). This makes the first part of your proof moot.

Comment: Also in your second paragraph, the fact that order of $\langle g^k\rangle$ is the order of $g^k$ has nothing to do with the fact that a subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. $\langle g^k\rangle$ is cyclic by definition, regardless of the group in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From where you are:

$n \vert kl$

Let $m = \gcd(n,k)$. Then (since $\gcd (\frac{n}{m}, \frac{k}{m}) = 1)\mid l \Rightarrow$

> $$\frac{n}{m} \leq l $$

But $(g^k)^{\frac{n}{m}} = g^{(n\frac{k}{m})}= e^{\frac{k}{m}}=e \Rightarrow$

> $$l \leq \frac{n}{m}$$

We conclude that:

$$l = \frac{n}{m}$$

Comment: Pellenthor, [what is the relation between 'the order of $x^k = n/{\gcd(k,n)}$' and this corollary of Lagrange's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2900950)?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $kl$ must be the **least** common multiple of $k$ and $n$.

Then make use of: $$nk=\gcd(n,k)\times\text{lcm}(n,k)$$

Comment: drhab, what do you think of [my proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896068) please?