# If $|G|=8$ Is Cyclic Then There Is $H\leq G$ Such That $|H|=4$ And $H$ Is Cyclic

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let there be $G$ a group such that $|G|=8$.

Prove: If $G$ is cyclic that it has a cyclic subgroup of order $4$

The options for the orders of a subgroup is $1,2,4,8$ so $4$ is a possibility.

Now $G=\{e,g,g^2,g^3,g^4,g^5,g^6,g^7\}$ has it is cyclic, taking $\langle \,g^2\mkern2mu\rangle=\{e,g^2,g^4,g^6\}$ is a cyclic subgroup of order $4$

I am asked, why is it obvious that the subgroup is cyclic? I know that every subgroup of a cyclic group is again cyclic, is there another reason here?

Comment: If you know that every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic, then you don't need another reason. Of course, the subgroup $\langle g^2\rangle$ is cyclic also because it is generated by a single element, namely $g^2$. There is nothing much going on here.

Comment: Is it obvious that the subgroup is cyclic? Yes, if you show that $g^2$ has order $4$. But since you know the order of $g^n$ in a cyclic group, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2217400/prove-that-the-order-of-the-cyclic-subgroup-langle-gk-rangle-is-n-operat), it is obvious.

Comment: @newhere You wrote $<g^2>$. What is it?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg That means "generated by". So it is the cyclic subgroup generated by the element $g^2$

Comment: @Luke My question was for the topic-starter.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Because it is only subgroup I could think of of order $4$

Comment: newhere, the group $C_2\times C_2$ is not cyclic and also has order $4$.