# Issue with Root of Unity Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers

I need some help with a proof:

Let $gcd(k,n)=1, w_n = e^{2*\pi*i/n}$ and $w_n^k = e^{2*\pi*i*k/n}$. Show that the equation $ <w_n> = <w_n^k>$ holds, where $<x>$ = {$x^n|n \in N_0 $}

Is it necessary to show, that $w_n^k$ is primitive, if $gcd(k,n)=1$ holds?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary. But it has been shown already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216020/if-g-is-the-generator-of-a-group-g-order-n-when-is-gk-a-generator), i.e., $g^k$ is also a generator, if and only if $gcd(n,k)=1$.

Comment: Welcome the Mathematics Stack Exchange community. A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site  will help you get the most of your time here.