# If G is a finite cyclic group of size n is generated by g, is it generated by $g^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, finitely-generated

In the solution to this problem I've been given by my professor, he says that $g^2$ generates G if n is odd but not if n is even. I am confused about this since I came up with the example that $Z/8$ is generated by 3 and also by 9, since 9 is congruent to 1, but this contradicts his answer. Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: The operation of $\mathbb Z / 8\mathbb Z$ is addition modulo $8$. So "squaring" in this context corresponds to "adding twice", not literal squaring, so  your $g^2$ would be $3 + 3 = 6 \mod 8$ and indeed $6$ doesn't generate the group.

Comment: If $g$ has order $n$, then $g^k$ generates $G$ if $\gcd(n,k)=1$ - see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216020/if-g-is-the-generator-of-a-group-g-order-n-when-is-gk-a-generator) for example. So if $n$ is odd, it is true for $k=2$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $g$ is the generator of a group $G$, order $n$, when is $g^k$ a generator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216020/if-g-is-the-generator-of-a-group-g-order-n-when-is-gk-a-generator)

Answer (score 3):

You are confused because $g^2$ doesn't mean "$g$ to the power of $2$", the concept of "power" isn't even well defined for an arbitrary group. Instead, it is literally defined as $gg$. Now in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ addition is the group operation. And so it becomes $g+g$. With that you have $3+3=6$ and $6$ is of order $4$, thus it doesn't generate $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$.